# cordova file transfer gives me an error code 1

Tags: android, plugins, upload, file-transfer, ngcordova

I've been struggling with the cordova file transfer, I've been reading tutorials and blogs telling me how to do it and it seem so easy but I just can't make it work.

My app is recording an video i manage to get the file url and add it as src to a video element and it plays just fine, no problem.

I then encrypt the file using a custom plugin saving it as .bin file.

but when i use the same url for the cordovaFileTransfer all I get is an error code 1. (which means File Not Found)

I tried chunkedMode = false and true but it makes no difference.

I even tried without encrypting and used the same url I use for the video element in html. (file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20151211_014038.mp4) together with mimeType: video/mp4

Am I supposed to use a special cordova filepath for the upload or what am I doing wrong?

There is a 400 http_status code in error but I thought I might try to fix the file_not_found first.

Very thankful for any help on this.

Regards

code:

```
var options = {
    mimeType : 'application/octet-stream',
    chunkedMode: false,
    fileName : '6ad8914898dc83a4f3ff841780c8dc0a.bin',
    headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + projectToken,
         'Content-Type': undefined
    }

}


$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, 'file:///data/data/com.myapp/files/temp/6ad8914898dc83a4f3ff841780c8dc0a.bin', options)
.then(function(result) {
     // Success!
     console.log("SUCCESS");
}, function(err) {
     // Error
     console.log("err: "+JSON.stringify(err));
}, function (progress) {
     // constant progress updates
});
```

here is the error object:

```
 {"code":1,
"source":"file:///data/data/com.myapp/files/temp/6ad8914898dc83a4f3ff841780c8dc0a.bin",
"target":"https://myapi.com:8090/api/message/e5ac7066-e8e1-4cb8-9183-d4d360fc94e3/content",
"http_status":400,
"body":null,
"exception":"https://myapi.com:8090/api/message/e5ac7066-e8e1-4cb8-9183-d4d360fc94e3/content"}
```

Comment: Does this work if you specify another endpoint, for example http://cordova-filetransfer.jitsu.com/upload (file-transfer test server)? What if you delete `Content-Type` header completely from the options?

Comment: nope that didn't work...
still got the same error.

Comment: Can it be related to how I store the mp4 when capturing the video? I use the media-capture plugin and the source is set on capture success callback function(data). data[0].fullPath is used as src to the video element in html and i use the same src when trying to send to server...

Comment: Does it work if you don't specify mimeType and therefore force multipart/form-data? You can also try to [convert the path to cdvfile](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#cdvfile-protocol) first.